# CSS or Greasemonkey to target heading element within an <a> element

Tags: html, css, greasemonkey

I had been using Greasemonkey to successfully turn visited links red on [Udemy's browse pages](https://www.udemy.com/courses/lifestyle/all-courses/?ordering=newest&lang=en).

The following had been successful:

```
// @match         http*://www.udemy.com/*
// @run-at        document-start
// @grant         GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
GM_addStyle ( " a:visited, .fl:visited { color: #CC0000 !important ;}     " );
```

But Udemy changed the page and now the titles which I want to turn red after being visited look something like this:

```
<div class="card__head"> 
<a class="card__title" ng-href="/essential-cooking-skills/" ng-click="track('course-title')" href="/essential-cooking-skills/"> 
    <h1 ng-bind-html="::course.title">Essential Cooking Skills</h1>
</a>
```

I've tried to target the h1 within the a tag by using `a.card__title.h1:visited` but that doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: `a.card__title:visited h1`

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm, that worked perfectly.